# Почему "стрЕножить"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Известно, что "стреножить" означает связать какие-нибудь две ноги у лошади или коровы, чтобы они не ушли далеко, т.е. получается, что у животных в таком случае будут "три ноги". Но почему слово пишется с буквой "е"?

Comment: Поправлю не по сути вопроса. Когда "стреноживают" скотину, то связывают не две, а три ноги, обычно две передние и одну заднюю. Ибо если связать только две из них, животное не успокоится и будет и дальше прыгать-брыкаться. Так мне в детстве дед на селе объяснял.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слово **стреножить** объясняется как происходящее от *трь*- и *нога* [др.-рус. трьнога - «путы на три ноги», от которого происходит рус. глаг. *треножить* (о лошади) «связывать передние ноги с одной задней» (ср. укр. *триножити* — тожд.) от "три ноги"]. Гласный Ь в слове *трьнога* преобразовался в Е в результате процесса падения редуцированных и вокализации гласных (в русском языке ‹ъ> изменилось в <о>, <ь> — в <э>, который на письме передается буквой Е после мягких согласных). Поэтому пишется *стр**е**ножить,  тр**е**ух, тр**е**ножник, тр**е**угольник, тр**е**звонить*. :-))

Answer (score 2):

В ***словаре Фасмера*** есть статья о приставке ТРЕ- и слове ТРЕНОЖИТЬ:

**Тре-** Ближайшая этимология: -- приставка при цслав. прил-ных, а также при превосход - ной степени прилагательных, Тресвятоґй, Тресвеґтлый, русск.-цслав. Трьгубъ "тройной", Трьногъ "треножник", ст.-слав. трьблаженъ TrismakЈrioj, трьвеличьствьнъ Trismљgistoj (Супр.). Дальнейшая этимология: Ср. лит. trigal~vis "трехголовый", tri°gubas "тройной", др.-инд. tripaґd - "трехногий", авест. ±rikamЌrЌ‹a - "трехголовый", греч. Tr…pouj "треножник", Trigљrwn, Tr…douloj, Trif…lhtoj (Кречмер, Glotta 12, 52; 22, 103), лат. tripЊs "трехногий"; см. Кречмер, там же; Вакернагель -- Дебруннер 3, 347. Далее связано с др.-инд. tris· "трижды". ( http://fasmerbook.com/p725.htm)

**Треноґжить**, Ближайшая этимология: Уже в Пов. о Бове (Гудзий, Хрестом. 293). От Трь- и Ногаґ. Ошибочно сближает Горяев (ЭС 375) с лат. stringЎ, - еrе "привязывать", нов.-в.-н. Strick "веревка".

Спасибо за вопрос.

Comment: Вряд ли только при церковнославянских.

Comment: Спасибо, Катя! Очень интересно.

Answer (score 1):

И "тренога" тоже с Е. И трезубец. В чем соменния? Здесь "тре" от "трёх" (трехглавый, трехкратный).

"Три..." в таких случаях - редкость великая. 
Впрочем "тре" (а не трёх) тоже встречается нечасто, в основном существительных и почему-то - в сочетании с частями тела.

Comment: Спасибо, безымянный коллега! Интересно и доступно!

Comment: Здесь "тре" не от "трёх", потому что -ёх - это окончание, которое в словообразовании не принимает никакого участия. Тре- от трь-, где Ь в результате вокализации становится Е (равно как Ъ становится О).